# How to deal with async request and display the data properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a badge component on my html page to indicate how many unread messages. Html code:

```html
<button class="font" mat-menu-item routerLink="/message">
  <mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon>
  <span [matBadgeHidden]="newMessageNum === 0" matBadge={{newMessageNum}} matBadgeOverlap="false" matBadgeColor="warn">Messages</span>
</button>
```

The variable newMessageNum is obtained through http request to backend. Code:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
    res => {
      if (res) {
        this.currentUser = res;
        this.messageService.getNewMessagesNum(this.currentUser.username).subscribe(
          res => {
            if (res.success) this.newMessageNum = res.number;
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        )
      }
    }
  )
}
```

However the problem is when I log into my website the newMessageNum is 0 and the badge is hidden even if I have several new messages, after I refresh the page, the badge comes out. I think it has something to do with the async request. I'm new at this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: the value set if you open the website while being logged in and it's considered 0 if you opened the website not logged then logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to angular not properly updating your component after getting the response from the server. So you have to invoke change detection, use either `ngZone` or `ChangeDetectorRef`.

example:

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){
  ...
  ...
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
    res => {
     if (res) {
       this.currentUser = res;
       this.messageService.getNewMessagesNum(this.currentUser.username).subscribe(
       res => {
         if (res.success) {
            this.newMessageNum = res.number;
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
         }
       },
       err => console.log(err)
       )
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: I think maybe the logic of my program is problematic. The code above is originally in header component, so it is loaded before login. So there will be an error because there is no user before login. So I think I should put this code into other component, and after logging in I need to kind of inform the header component that of the newMessageNum value and make the badge display. Do you know how to pass value from one component to the header component?Thanks!

Comment: Solved, by watching this great video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM